# how to get the datetimes before and after some specific dates in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like

```
col1
2015-02-02
2015-04-05
2016-07-02
```

I would like to add, for each date in col 1, the `x` days before and `x` days after that date.

That means that the resulting DataFrame will contain more rows (specifically, n(1+ 2*x), where n is the orignal number of dates in `col1`)

How can I do that in a proper Pandonic way?

Output would be (for `x=1`)

```
col1
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
2015-04-04
etc
```

Thanks!

Comment: does you DF have only one column: `col1`?

Comment: yes, that is basically a DataFrame of dates. If needed, we can use it as a Series as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way, but I'm not sure that it's the best / fastest way to do it:

```
In [143]: df
Out[143]:
        col1
0 2015-02-02
1 2015-04-05
2 2016-07-02

In [144]: %paste
N = 2
(df.col1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x - pd.Timedelta(days=N),
                                                 x + pd.Timedelta(days=N))
                         )
         )
        .stack()
        .drop_duplicates()
        .reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
        .to_frame(name='col1')
)
## -- End pasted text --
Out[144]:
         col1
0  2015-01-31
1  2015-02-01
2  2015-02-02
3  2015-02-03
4  2015-02-04
5  2015-04-03
6  2015-04-04
7  2015-04-05
8  2015-04-06
9  2015-04-07
10 2016-06-30
11 2016-07-01
12 2016-07-02
13 2016-07-03
14 2016-07-04
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this takes a dataframe with a `datetime.date` column and then stacks another `Series` underneath with `timedelta` shifts to the original data.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 2)}, {'date': datetime.date(2016, 1, 1)}], columns=['date'])
df = pd.concat([df.date, df.date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)], ignore_index=True).to_frame()
```

Comment: excellent thanks but the point is to have everything staked-up in one column

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Vertical stacking like this?

Comment: look at my output, you can see that col1 contains more rows. It contains the originals dates but also the dates before and after these days.

Comment: thanks noel, so to get the desired output I should use a loop?

Comment: With my answer, using `pd.concat`, you'd need a for loop, yes.